# TPL Split Block

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a parallel processing problem as follows:

A series of messages are received from a source. They need to be processed in parallel, however they need to be processed in order based on a property. Basically, an `ActionBlock<Message>` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1` per group.

```cs
interface Message 
{ 
    string GroupId { get; } 
    Task Process(); 
}
```

i.e. Messages can be processed simultaneously from different groups, however at any point in time only 1 message from each group can be processed.   However, I cannot devise a thread-safe way to create these blocks without winding up with the blocks sitting around in memory for groups that will not come again.

Comment: How about creating processing task queue per GroupIDs and sending messages to each queue ? processing queues, will work individualy and will be thread safe. I don't see a reason to use Parallel class for this.

Comment: Yes, that would work. I would have to lock on the queue in order to delete it (if the queue is empty for a Group, no point keeping it around).  I think that will work.

Comment: An ActionBlock maintains order no matter the DOP. Besides DOP is 1 by default. Doing this per group is another matter - and may not even require grouping. How many possible groups are there? And what is `Process()`? In a Dataflow pipeline the code is in the blocks, not the messages. Concurrency is provided because each block in the pipeline can work on different messages. Putting the code in the message is equivalent to putting the .... script in the command output of a batch pipeline instead of just letting the CLI tools do their job

Comment: If you have proper messages, ie no `Process()` code, you can create one ActionBlock per group and use LinkTo's predicate to redirect each message to the correct ActionBlock or TransformBlock. You can even have different code per block if that's necessary

Comment: `the blocks sitting around in memory` why would that be a problem? An ActionBlock is stateless and a worker task isn't an actual thread that's wasted. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? There may be a better way of solving it, better suited to Dataflow. You could, for example, link using a hash of the `GroupId` that redirects consistently to one of a few blocks. You'd get both concurrent processing and in-order processing

Comment: The `Process()` method is used by the dataflow block (just there for illustration).  The reason is that the block is a long-running worker process that will process potentially millions of messages, where each group has < 100 members.  Therefore, creating a block per group (which was of course my original idea) would result in a huge number of ActionBlocks which will never be used again.  The Hash of `GroupId` is a good idea, however.